# Ckeditor selection drag and drop on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor

Chrome has a different behaviour when dragging and dropping some selection into the editor, for test you can use the demo page for cheditor http://ckeditor.com/demo

On Chrome you must drop the selection on the exact line where the cursor/caret is located
but in Firefox I can drop anywhere, I would like to have same thing in Chrome too so drag-drop is easy for the user
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try fixing the width and height of HTML and BODY inside the iframe of CKEditor to be 100%. 
The drop works only in the body tag of CKeditor and Chrome is not expanding the body tag like the Mozilla Firefox browser.

Have a nice day.